# Is it possible to to encypt a USB and not allow anyone to open any file without a password?

Tags: usb, encryption

Is it possible for me to put any file that I want on a flash drive, without any keys, but have really long passwords, and no body can open any file without the password, even if the USB is unlocked from the password before. So the USB has a password, and also selected files have passwords, and be system-agnostic, so I can open it on any operating system, Linux, Windows, Mac, etc.

Comment: You could encrypt the disk but you would need a cross-platform mechanism - BitLocker (Win only), TrueCrypt (not sure if it works on Mac?)(TrueCrypt is also now no longer maintained as of quite recently?) Etc. That's your first problem. The files problem is the same. You can password protect Office documents but Linux can't read them. A possible solution is to not encrypt the drive but use a secure compressed file type such as 7-Zip or RAR...

Comment: TrueCrypt is really the only cross platform encryption platform even though it won't be updated it should be fine to use.  Otherwise give up the cross platform requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt).

It's multi-os and multi-platform (windows, linux, mac, 32 bit, 64 bit).

However - it may take some time before you learn to use it with USB stick.

There are also encrtypted USB drives (with internal encryption module), but you may have to do some research to find stick with encrytpion and multi-os support.